# How can I specify what schemas ( or indices ) I want to query from Gentics Mesh (no graphQL API)

Tags: gentics-mesh

So I'm using Gentics Mesh and a "middleware". From this middleware, I'm making a request to the `mesh` API that forwards requests to `elasticSearch`. At moment I don't want to use GraphQL API so that's why I'm using `/rawSearch`.
The problem becomes that in such query it will query **all** indices and I would like to decide which one it queries, just like `elasticSearch` does, for example, `/index1,index2/_search.` Is it possible to limit the search to specific indexes or am I forced to use GraphQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to provide the exact index name yourself.

Maybe it useful for your use case to use the `/api/v2/:projectName/rawSearch` which narrows the indices down to a certain project within mesh.

Comment: Mesh creates 2 index per schema, draft and published, by your approach I will narrow the query but it will still query for all *-draft indices even if I want only to query *-published ones.

Comment: @JavierVelando That's not correct. Mesh will search in either -draft or -published indices (depending on ?version query parameter)

Comment: @Jotschi Thank you very much. But I couldn't find this info in the docs.
https://getmesh.io/docs/api/#rawSearch_nodes_post

Just btw can you confirm that queries cant be done against only certain schemas (indices)?

Comment: @JavierVelando Yes, queries are always run against all schemas. We already plan to optimize this by adding a filter query parameter. This way only specific indices would be hit. (e.g. schemas=content,folder). Thanks for the feedback. We'll update the docs.